# Reply screen design / element placement for tablet app

Tags: accessibility, ipad, tablet

This mobile tablet app displays full screen photos with a reply button.  When the user (a senior over 65 years of age) clicks reply, a modal reply screen slides up from the bottom as shown below.

Question #1.  Should the photo be represented on this reply screen and if so how large? Current design has a 25% scaled version of the photo which takes up a lot of screen real estate and adds clutter, but it's there because we're targeting seniors.

Question #2. For reply, I have a text input box and also the ability for the user to select from a list of canned responses. There will be no more than 10 generic ( i.e. non-AI) responses available. Currently they are in a scrolling vertical table view above the text input box to the right of the photo. Is the table view the optimal way to present the canned responses, or would a picker work better (ios) and should this be above or below the text input box?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The image is a bit large, but this may be a design guideline. I think there are more important structuring and design problems.

The most obvious:

**Problem:** There's no clear difference between the received message and the message to be sent. In fact the title `Reply` occupies the whole screen width and leads to confusion.

**Solution:** Make a clear difference between the container field of the received message and the sending message.

---

**Problem:** the fields with canned responses don't seem selectable items

**Solution:** make them look more like buttons or use a picker element instead

---

**Problem:** The background color of the canned responses is practically the same as that of the text input box, this makes them look the same type of component.

**Solution:** contrast more each type of element.

---

**Problem:** All interaction elements are grouped on the right of the screen, except `Cancel`.

**Solution:** Group all the interaction elements in the same activity area. If it's necessary to show that `Cancel` is apart from the rest of the elements, give greater visual presence to both: `Cancel` and `Send`.

---

(This is personal) The separation lines between the selectable elements have no function, generate noise and visually unify the group preventing the immediate interpretation of selectable units.

---

I think the example screen is a starting point, but not a final design. I would study the following points in general terms taking into account the type of end user:

1. Differentiate well the area of ​​the received message and the message to be sent
2. Contrast each element or group of elements according to their function
3. Highlight or differentiate, the final CTA buttons `Cancel` and `Send` from the rest of the components